# Why does SharePoint 2010 Excel WebPart not find Excel spreadsheet in Share Documents?

Tags: document-library, excel, excel-services

I have a **SharePoint 2010** single instance. The Web site has an Excel worksheet in `Shared Documents`, which I can navigate to as a user.

- I have enabled Excel services.
- I have activated Excel services proxy.
- The Web application is associated with the Excel Services service
  application
  (through `Central Administration --> Application
  Management --> Configure service applications associations.`)

Remotely I can **Check Out** the Site Page, edit the Site Page, edit the WebPart. Here I select the WorkBook through the elipsis button on the properties of the WebPart. Everything seems good at this point, as I can find the Workbook easily this way.

When I click **"Apply"**, I get the error message:

> "The file that you selected could not be found. Check the spelling of
>   the file name and verify that the location is correct. Make sure that
>   the file has not been renamed, moved or deleted."

I also get this error message when I simply navigate to Shared Documents remotely.

NOTE: When I copy the URL of my worksheet from the WebPart property, Workbook, to a browser, I can open the file after an authentication challenge.

Answer (score 0):

Excel services will only work with spreadsheets that are in a trusted location - you can set trusted locations in the Excel Services settings in Central Admin.

Comment: What do you mean? The spreadsheet is in the Shared Documents of the same SP Site?

Comment: In CA you define which sites/libraries are trusted locations - just because it is in SharePoint does not necessarily mean it is in a trusted location.